# Example for LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

Could some kind person show me an example of how to use `LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST`?

I've tried the following code, but both the return value of `SendMessage()` and the relevant members of `myinfo` are always -1, no matter where in my ListView I click.

```
case NM_RCLICK:
{
    NMITEMACTIVATE itemClicked = *(NMITEMACTIVATE*)lParam;
    LVHITTESTINFO myinfo;
    memset(&myinfo, 0, sizeof(myinfo));
    POINT cursorPos;
    GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
    myinfo.pt = cursorPos;
    // I find that itemNumber as well as myinfo->iItem and myinfo->iSubItem
    // are always set to -1 by the following line
    int itemNumber = SendMessage(myListviewHwnd, LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST, 0,(LPARAM)&myinfo);
}
```

I based my code off of the following MSDN articles:

[NM_RCLICK (list view) notification code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774873.aspx)

[LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761229.aspx)

But they don't list any examples, so I'm worried I'm doing something stupid :(

Comment: `LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST` wants client coordinates, you're giving it screen coordinates.

Comment: @Jnathan Potter Thank you, that was it. Knew it was going to be something stupid.

Comment: @aquirdturtle If you have an answer for your question, write an answer instead of updating your question with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I was doing something stupid. The LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST function wants client coordinates, not screen coordinates. Here's a working example:

```
case NM_RCLICK:
{
    NMITEMACTIVATE itemClicked = *(NMITEMACTIVATE*)lParam;
    LVHITTESTINFO myinfo;
    memset(&myinfo, 0, sizeof(myinfo));
    POINT cursorPos;
    GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
    ScreenToClient(myListviewHwnd, &cursorPos);
    myinfo.pt = cursorPos;
    int itemNumber = SendMessage(myListviewHwnd, LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST, 0, (LPARAM)&myinfo);
}
```

Comment: You do not need to use `GetCursorPos()` and `ScreenToClient()` at all.  The `NM_RCLICK` notification gives you the client coordinates where the click occurred, they are in the `NMITEMACTIVATE::ptAction` field: "*`POINT` structure that indicates the location at which the event occurred, in client coordinates.*"  So you can do this instead: `myinfo.pt = itemClicked->ptAction;`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved the same issue like this:

```
LVHITTESTINFO lvHit;
memset(&lvHit,0, sizeof(LVHITTESTINFO));
lvHit.pt = pNMItemActivate->ptAction;

m_list.SubItemHitTest(&lvHit);  // !! Use SubItemHitTest, not HitTest


iItem    = lvHit.iItem;
iSubItem = lvHit.iSubItem;
```